# How can I get the color from a pixel on the screen in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I would like to render a photograph, and allow the user to select a color by touching on it. However I cannot find anyway to retrieve the painted pixels under the touch event.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

See this example..

Using OntouchListener to detect your touch on imageView..

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        float[] eventXY = new float[]{eventX, eventY};

        int x = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[0]);
        int y = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[1]);

        Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView) view).getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgDrawable).getBitmap();

        //Limit x, y range within bitmap
        if (x < 0) {
            x = 0;
        } else if (x > bitmap.getWidth() - 1) {
            x = bitmap.getWidth() - 1;
        }

        if (y < 0) {
            y = 0;
        } else if (y > bitmap.getHeight() - 1) {
            y = bitmap.getHeight() - 1;
        }

        int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

        int r = Color.red(touchedRGB);
        int b = Color.blue(touchedRGB);
        int g = Color.green(touchedRGB);

        String rr = Integer.toString(r);
        String bb = Integer.toString(g);
        String gg = Integer.toString(b);

        String xyz = (rr+bb+gg);

        colorRGB.setText("touched color: " + "#" + xyz);
```

here xyz is your rgb color code..

Comment: I guess I could use that approach (reading the x+y over the pic frame and then reading the same position within the pixel array of the image), however I was looking for an approach using react-native APIs. So it would be also compatible with iOS solutions. I'll try anyways.